# How to remap a topic to sub namespaces

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remapping, namespace, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have a node, `io_node`, that provides a service, `service`, and publishes on a topic, `topic`. I also have nodes of type `client_node` and `client_node2` (both named `client_node`) that use `service` and subscribe to `topic`. The client_nodes are in two different namespaces, `a` and `b` for various reasons.

So `rosnode list` would show:

```
/io_node
/a/client_node
/b/client_node
```

The problem is that I can't get remapping to work with my launch files no matter where I put the remap tags.  I want the two client nodes to subscribe to `/topic` and use `/service`, but they subscribe to their namespace instead (for example, `/a/client_node` subscribes `/a/topic` and tries to use `/a/service`).

`rostopic list` shows

```
/topic
/a/topic
/b/topic
```

Here's one version of the top level launch file:

```
<launch>
   <include file=$(find io_node)/launch/io.launch"/>

   <group>
     <remap from="topic" to="a/topic"/>
     <include file=$(find client_node)/launch/client.launch" ns="a"/>
   </group>

   <group>
     <remap from="topic" to="b/topic"/>
     <include file=$(find client_node2)/launch/client.launch" ns="b"/>
   </group>
</launch>
```

And here's a `client.launch` (client_node2 is similar):

```
<launch>
        <node pkg="client_node" name="client_node" type="client_node" output="screen" respawn="true"/>
</launch>
```

The whole top level launch file is going to be used in yet another launch file, with multiple instances of the three nodes being used in one system only with different namespaces, so I don't think I can use global namespaces.  I've tried

- putting the ns tag in a group tag in the client launch files
- putting the ns tag in the launch tag in the client launch files and putting ns in the node tag
- putting the ns tag in the group tag in the top level launch file
- putting the remap tag in the node tag in the client launch file
- putting the remap tag in the group tag in the client launch file
- changing the remap to be from="a/topic" to="topic"

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Guess I should say that I filed [an enhancement request](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/236).  In the meantime, my quick fix was to ditch the namespaces and use the names `client_node_a` and `client_node_b` to make them both in the same namespace, and thus both able to use `/topic`. This isn't really the solution I wanted, though, and isn't really all that flexible...

I tried Boris's suggestion, too, and it works, but I have a bunch of launch files that makes argument passing tedious.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60343/how-to-remap-a-topic-to-sub-namespaces/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5539/tfurf/) on 2013-07-24**:
I recently came across this same problem, I don't know the best fix, but just want to say I think the lack of functionality here (I would venture to say "bug") makes it really hard to scale larger projects without some kind of name collision.

**Comment by [Max Pfingsthorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4191/max-pfingsthorn/) on 2013-07-24**:
Related question: http://answers.ros.org/question/12105/can-i-access-the-absolute-or-parent-namespace-of-a-node-from-within-a-launch-file/

**Comment by [tfurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5539/tfurf/) on 2013-07-24**:
With a temporary workaround: http://answers.ros.org/question/12105/can-i-access-the-absolute-or-parent-namespace-of-a-node-from-within-a-launch-file/?answer=68866#post-id-68866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like if you specify a path to a topic without leading `/` the whole string is treated as a topic name and obviously cannot be found. So remapping from `foo` to `bar` will work, but `baz/foo` to `bar` will not.

Specifying the absolute path to the topic to be remapped solves it, i.e. remapping from `/baz/foo` to `bar` will result in `/baz/bar` and from `/baz/foo` to `/bar` gives `/bar`.

P.S. Honestly remapping is a very confusing technique and I personally prefer to specify topic names as node parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-04-10**:
I would do that, but the launch file I called top-level won't really be top-level in the future.  It will be used multiple times, each instance launched in another namespace. So /alpha/topic, /beta/topic and so on, and I don't know how many there will be or what their names will be.  Thanks though.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-04-10**:
Maybe using arguments is the only way then, I mean `<arg>` tags with corresponding `$(arg)` calls.